# Document Library UI Help Required

Tags: interaction-design, interface, user-centered-design

We have a hundreds of documents that I'm struggling to decide how to present to users. I think a searchable/filterable library allowing users to drill down to what it is they require would be the optimal solution, however I'm not sure about patterns or UX for this.

Ideally we'd want to be able to use the following filters:

- Audience (Educators, Learners, Practitioners)
- Content type (Presentations, Lesson plans, Worksheets, Eligibility Wheels pdfs, Factsheets, Mainstream Medicine Factsheets, Genomics Conditions Factsheets, Reports, Publications)
- Document type (Worksheet, Factsheet, Lesson Plan, Report, Publication, Presentation)
- Medical Condition -(only relevant to certain content types)
- Profession - (only relevant to certain content types)
- Keyword

Does anyone else have any good examples of something similar?

The only example I have been able to find is: http://library.mitsubishielectric.co.uk/

Comment: how are the results presented at the moment? is it a table? is it a list?

Comment: @DimitraMiha Nothing exists at the moment.

Comment: I think something like this looks appropriate: https://www.gov.uk/government/publications, with perhaps a browse option alongside.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, well I've mocked this up, and I think it's the approach I'm going to take. If anyone can think of any improvements please say so in the comments.

It is my intention to make the labels clickable so they can act as filters themselves.

[image: Doc Library UI]